# How to Add New Customer or Customer Group in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I am facing an issue with adding a new customer group from Backend at Magento 2.3 Could you please help me on adding a new customer group page from the backend, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Helper\Data;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    protected $customerFactory;
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $loginHelper;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        Config $eavConfig,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->loginHelper     = $helper;
    }

    public function install( ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create( ['setup' => $setup] );
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'is_admin',
            [
                'type'         => 'int',
                'label'        => 'is_admin',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => false,
                'position'     => 999,
                'default'      => 0
            ]
        );
        $sampleAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute( Customer::ENTITY, 'is_admin' );

        $sampleAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer']
        );
        $sampleAttribute->save();

        $configEmail = $this->loginHelper->getConfigEmail();
        $websiteId = ( int )$this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getId();
        $isEmailNotExists = $this->customerAccountManagement->isEmailAvailable( $configEmail, $websiteId );

        if ( $isEmailNotExists == true ) {
            $data = [
                'firstname' => 'admin',
                'lastname' => 'admin',
                'email' => $configEmail,
                'password'=>'admin123',
                'is_admin'=>'1'
            ];

            $this->customerFactory->create()->setData( $data )->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

please check the following steps for adding:

1. a customer from the backend: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/customers/account-create.html#create-a-new-account-from-the-admin
2. a new customer group https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/customers/customer-groups.html#create-a-customer-group